# What is a peer in IBM Bluemix blockchain?

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain

I am working on IBM Bluemix Blockchain. I realized that IBM only offers 4 peers  for a very expensive package (see attached image). Tried to read through glossaries and key terms but still got confused. I suppose that it is not relevant to peer concept in p2p network. Wish someone here can help me to answer my question.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The peers in the IBM Bluemix Blockchain offering are 4 peers on a peer-to-peer network. They are included in the free Blockchain starter developer plan, as well as the High-Security Business Network plan that you reference.  See the [Blockchain entry](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/blockchain?taxonomyNavigation=apps) in the Bluemix Catalog.

As this question is not about programming, there is a good chance it will be voted down or removed. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You can ask questions about the Bluemix offerings at [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/).

Answer (score 0):

IBM Bluemix Blockchain is a hosted version of Hyperledger fabric. (Both versions 0.6 and 1.0 alpha are supported; the latter only as a free "preview".) Consequently, you should check out the fabric documentation. Your question is answered by the project Glossary: a peer is "A network entity that maintains a ledger and runs chaincode containers in order to perform read/write operations to the ledger. Peers are owned and maintained by members." [Hyperledger fabric documentation - Glossary](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glossary.html)

And I agree that this is not a good question here.